# Compute a value for a base constructor AND access that value afterwards?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

In the below code snippet:

```cs
public MyClass(string arg) : base(ComputeSomethingExpensive(arg))
{
    this.OriginalArg = arg;
    this.SomethingExpensive = ComputeSomethingExpensive(arg);
}

private static object ComputeSomethingExpensive(string arg) => // something expensive
```

Is there any way to avoid two calls to `ComputeSomethingExpensive` (e.g. create an identifier for the statically computed base class argument) - assuming the base class doesn't "store" the supplied argument in any accessible members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah, I just thought of this - create a second constructor:

```cs
public MyClass(string arg) : this(ComputeSomethingExpensive(arg))
{
    this.OriginalArg = arg;
}

private MyClass(object somethingExpensive) : base(somethingExpensive)
{
    this.SomethingExpensive = somethingExpensive;
}

private static object ComputeSomethingExpensive(string arg) => // something expensive
```

Hopefully that helps someone else.

**Sample implementation**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QNNilB

Comment: I was just about to post this same thing. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: This won't compile.

Comment: @TanveerBadar it does if you implement the presumably obvious surrounding class, local members, and "something expensive" code. See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QNNilB

Comment: There was a typo in the private constructor causing compiler error.